# Are Stack Exchange websites' UI/UX development still happening?

Tags: support, design

I am curious to know if the platform itself for Stack Exchange is still being developed from a UI/UX point of view. Personally I haven't seen much change over the years, so that's why I am asking.

- Is there a changelog for what's new?
- Can we suggest improvements?
- How is the development done: open-source, in-house, or agency?
- Can we expect anything as users of this platform?

Comment: See the [[tag:design]] tag, e.g. [some major upvoted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bdesign%5d%20%5bdiscussion%5d%20score%3a50%20is%3aq&searchOn=3).

Comment: Since this post is getting negative feedback, I imagine it's duplicated content. But as a newcomer, it's hard to figure out where to start. There should be an intro page describing how meta debates are handled, maybe in the Tour page. Changelog should be there, important tags should be there. Maybe I should suggest this as a feature request if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because we've recently got a bunch of somewhat questionable UI changes (mostly random color changes here and there).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well... everyone has to start somewhere, and color preferences are the easiest to express :)))

Comment: [Actual usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) is long dead. It has been replaced with statistics.

Comment: The website was sold a few years ago. It has transitioned from "grow the tree" mode to "pick the fruit" mode.

Comment: Regrettably, yes.

Answer (score 5):

- The closest we have to a changelog [is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)
- You can suggest improvements via [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions. Take care to check your feature hasn't already been suggested and note that requesting new features is quite hard i.e. if you haven't thought your feature through and don't provide good reasons it is important and useful it likely won't be received very well. Even if you get past those hurdles, there have been many well-received feature-requests but very very few have been implemented.
- Most of Stack Exchange is proprietary code. Some small parts, such as the [Stacks Editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor) are open source.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was also hoping to get an overall feeling of how the support is handled overall for this platform (basically my last question).

Comment: Your last question is simply too vague and too broad. Look through all the existing feature-request questions and see which ones have been completed, and which ones not perhaps.

Comment: Well, sure I could do that, but there is this thing called "information overload": this platform presents all information at once, which is too overwhelming for newcomers. But I agree that my question could have been better.

Comment: The recent feature changes is hardly a changelog and not maintained anymore, e.g. it lacks all the colors updates. Suggesting feature requests is possible but only very very few actually get done. (i.e. the way it's written here might cause one to think many requests are done, that's very far from reality.) /cc @Morc

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda I've added text to the answer to make it clear that feature requests rarely get implemented no matter how well received they are.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Now this is the kind of answer I was looking for in order to understand how debates and improvements are actually made :)
But it sounds sad, nonetheless.

Comment: @Morco the sad part is that it only getting worse.